# Database don't create 5th column

Tags: java, database, sqlite

i' ve a problem with my DB. I've created this table that works only with the first 4th column; when i try to run the app with the new inserted column codice i've this error:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Cuccioli has no column named Codice
```

E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Nome=Ff Codice=Namjje Sesso=Maschio Razza=Volpino
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Cuccioli has no column named Codice (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Cuccioli(Nome,Codice,Sesso,Razza) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

This is cretion table code

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + COLUMN_NOME + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_RAZZA + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_SESSO + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_CODICE + " TEXT"
                + ")";
```

Comment: the table was created before ?

Comment: The table doesn't have a column named Codice. Your create script did not finish successfully, you're working with a previous state of the database.

Comment: You can use `.schema` to see the structure of a table.

Comment: Apparently, the value of `COLUMN_CODICE` is not `codice`, but we can't be sure. You will need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Solved problem with linked question thanks